# how to install plasma-nm in elementary OS

Tags: linux, dependencies, debian-based

I want to install plasma-nm software in Elementary OS, which is not available in Software center. When I searched for .deb package, its asking for many dependencies. There are over a dozens of dependencies to install before install plasma-nm, downloading them individually and installing is very difficult.
is there any software or command which can download and install all dependencies for me?
`sudo apt-get install plasma-nm` is not helping.
 Also plasma-nm is not available in synaptic package manager.

Please help

Comment: use `dpkg -i plasma-nm.deb`

Comment: it says unmet dependencies

Comment: But it probably lists these unmet dependencies, and you might install them with `apt-get install`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying a lot, The problem was Elementary OS. Plasma-nm needs network-manager 0.9.8 or greater.

Need to install ubuntu 13.04 or greater for this. There is no support for elementary os regarding this (even though elementary is based on ubuntu, but an older version).

Good luck!

Please consider changing the name of the question to something like:

Installing plasma-nm in elementary OS

Comment: i cant find ppa. finding ppa was my first thought

Comment: what do you mean you can find ppa? did you do as I suggested?..I also use Elementary OS and with that i was able to install it correctly

Comment: Your answer didn't help. please remove -1 vote if it was you who voted it -1

Comment: what happens if you do: sudo apt-cache search plasma-nm ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63366/discussion-between-cesar-villasana-and-edward-torvalds).

Comment: hey, the problem why i was unable to install was you cant install KDE applet in GTK distro, as said by someone